# Absolute extrema of $t+\cot(1/2t)$

Tags: calculus

let $$f(t)=t+\cot(1/2t)$$

what are the absolute min and max on $[\pi/4, 7 \pi /4]$?

probably this question is too short so that I have to make it longer

sorry for this uesless sentences but I got no other choices.

Comment: Use the derivative test. Here are your critical points $3\pi/2, \pi/2$. Check the sign of the second derivative which tells you which gives max and that gives min.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Calculate the derivative, being particularly careful with minus signs. Also make sure that $\cot$ does not do strange things on our interval, such as blowing up.

**Remark:** There is some ambiguity in the description of the function. The analyses for $t+\cot\left(\frac{1}{2t}\right)$ and $t+\cot\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$ are quite different. I have assumed that your intended function is the first one, and the hint is specifically targeted to that, since the derivative turns out to be positive in that case. The hint is not inappropriate for the second possibility, but it is insufficiently specific.

Answer (score 0):

What is $f'(t)$? The absolute extrema (if any) will occur at either zeroes (or undefined points) of $f'(t)$ in the interior of the interval, or at the endpoints. Be sure that $f(t)$ doesn't diverge to $\pm\infty$ anywhere in the interval.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment. Here is the graph

[image]